# Styling a direct children

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      tbody > tr {
        color: grey
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Favourite films</th></tr>
        <tr><th>Title</th><th>Year</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>The Shawshank Redemption</td><td>1994</td></tr>
        <div>
          <tr><td>Django Unchained</td><td>2012</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Candyman</td><td>1992</td></tr>
        </div>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Why do rows which are inside div become too grey? I wrote tbody > tr, not tbody tr, so only the first row, which is the direct children of tbody, should become grey.

Comment: div can't be a child of tbody so your browser is probably auto correcting and removing it

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) :

- Permitted content : zero or more `<tr>` elements.

So your browser is ignoring your `div` inside the `<tbody>` element

You can try the following

```
tbody > tr:first-of-type
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw3s2/)

Also you can use :

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(1)
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw3s2/1/)

Comment: I think the OP knows that. But the problem here is the `<div>` inside the `<tbody>` that he tried to use as a workaround... I mean, the complete answer would be yours and the comment of @Pete

Comment: @user3546093 : Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

To select the first row you can simply do this

```
tbody > tr:first-child
```

You need to remove that div inside of tbody since it is invalid

Answer (score 0):

tbody > tr means first level of tr and not the first tr.Rest is all well explained.
Never put div inside tr,you can place it inside td if needed.